# Set hover image on radio button image

Tags: html, css

I have radio button input with image like below

```
 [image]       [image]      [image]
title image   title image  title image
```

I want to add hover image, so if user hover at radio button image, it will show another image. I have added hover css code, however it's just show image usual like below

```
  [image]
title image       
[image hover] 

  [image]      [image]
title image   title image
```

```css
/* HIDE RADIO */

[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* IMAGE STYLES */

[type=radio]+img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */

[type=radio]:checked+img {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
}

/* HOVER STYLES */

[type=radio]:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="option1" value="option1"  checked>
  <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/img/img-1.png" style="padding: 10px;" width="200" height="140">
  <p style="margin: 2px;text-align: center;">Title Image 1</p>
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/img/img-hover-1.png">
  </div>
</label>
<label>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="option2" value="option2">
  <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/img/img-2.png" style="padding: 10px;" width="200" height="140">
  <p style="margin: 2px;text-align: center;">Title Image 2</p>
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/img/img-hover-2.png">
  </div>
</label>
<label>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="option3" value="option3">
  <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/img/img-1.png" style="padding: 10px;" width="200" height="140">
  <p style="margin: 2px;text-align: center;">Title Image 3</p>
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/img/img-hover-3.png">
  </div>
</label>
```

I have put my code in [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/ichromes/h9oqf76t/3/) too.
Do you know how to fix this ? Thank you

Comment: please put the `jsfiddle` of your work so we can analysis it online.

Comment: `[type=radio]:hover .overlay` should be `[type=radio]:hover ~ .overlay` ?

Comment: Hi @sol, it's still not working

Comment: hi @mkafiyan, I have put the code in jsfiddle, I have added it on my question

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/gh9tsdr7/1/

Comment: hi@sol, yes it is